# Scatterplots: How do you select data larger or less than a certain value in R

Tags: r, plot, statistics

I know how to create a scatter plot, but how do you  select data larger or less than a certain value.

**Example:** Create a scatter-plot with the longitudes of earthquakes with a magnitude larger than 7 on the x axis, and the latitudes of earthquakes with a magnitude larger than 7 on the y axis

How do I code only earthquakes larger than 7?

What do I need to add to below script?

```r
plot(earthquakes$Latitude ~ earthquakes$Longitude)
```

Comment: By filtering the data source that is creating the scatterplot. If it's a data frame : data <- earthquakes[earthquakes$magnitude > 7, ]  then plot....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple hack version:

```
plot(earthquakes$Latitude[earthquakes$MW > 7] ~ earthquakes$Longitude[earthquakes$MW > 7] )
```

Though ideally you should be subsetting the data first.

Comment: Sorry, I left out some information. The dataset is earthquakes. There are 3 variables in the set: - MW: magnitude of the earthquake, Longitude: Longitude of the earthquake, Latitude: Latitude of the earthquake. I need to make mw above 7 for the latitude variable and the longitude variable

Comment: @JaredZissou: When you access data in R generically through the $ operator it takes it as a vector as in your case you have (most likely) a dataframe. Try what I have done and see what happens next. Updated the answer. Carl's suggestion is the more methodical way though

Comment: Look at the docs for dplyr....I left chaining out for simplicity but it's ideal for slicing data